# LyX error classicthesis.sty not found

Tags: errors, lyx, classicthesis

I have used miktex to install the package classicthesis.

I have installed the classicthesis layout file.

When I run my file I get a:   LateX error: File ../classicthesis.sty not found.

I assumed that miktex has placed the classicthesis style file in the correct folder.
Where should it go?

Comment: The .sty file should go to `MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\classicthesis\` and the documentation to `MiKTeX 2.9\doc\latex\classicthesis\`. You should check with MiKTeX console whether it is installed?

Comment: I have just found the .sty file in the correct folder, as you suggested. However, I am still getting the same error.

Comment: Try running `MiKTeX Settings`, `Refresh FNDB`, both as user and as administrator.

Comment: Looks like LaTeX is trying to find the file in the parent folder of your document's folder, thus ../    What does the call to classicthesis in your document look like? (the \usepackage command)

Comment: This message was cross-posted here: https://www.mail-archive.com/search?l=mid&q=5abf6bf3.d6df620a.17ca1.127f%40mx.google.com. @AnthonyMacks please read the following: https://latex.org/home/latex-community/94-etiquette/454-crossposts

Comment: Problem solved. I changed the preamble so that classicthesis.sty could be found.

Comment: @AnthonyMacks mind sharing how you changed the preamble?

Comment: I simply added the line: \usepackage{classicthesis}